# template won't evaluate fields that are interface type as the underlying type

Tags: interface, struct, go, field

Using golang `html/template` (same behavior with `text/template`). If I have a struct with a member that is of an interface type, I cannot access members of the underlying type (specifically trying to access fields that are on a struct that implements interface `InnerInterface` but is return via the `InnerInterface` interface type, not the struct type).

http://play.golang.org/p/ZH8wSK83oM

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "html/template"

type InnerInterface interface{ InnerSomeMethod() }

type MyInnerStruct struct { Title string }
func (mis MyInnerStruct)InnerSomeMethod() { fmt.Println("Just to show we're satisfying the interface") }

type MyOuterStruct struct { Inner InnerInterface }


func main() {

    fmt.Println("Starting")


    arg := MyOuterStruct{Inner:MyInnerStruct{Title:"test1"}}

    err := template.Must(template.New("testtmpl").Parse("{{.Inner.Title}}")).Execute(os.Stdout, arg)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }

}
```

Changing: `type MyOuterStruct struct { Inner InnerInterface }` to a totally generic interface, i.e. `type MyOuterStruct struct { Inner interface{} }` makes it render properly.  This leads me to believe that `interface{}` is treated specially by the rendering engine.

Is there a better way to do this than to use `interface{}` whenever I want to be able to dynamically evaluate fields like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct with saying that `interface{}` is handled differently by the rendering
engine. Only `interface{}` values are unpacked, interface values that have a method set are not.
I suppose the reasoning behind this is that if you have a interface type, you specifically limit the type to the method set. Therefore, you don't want the template engine trying to access members that may lie behind that interface.

The 'problem' is caused by the function [`indirect` in `exec.go`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/text/template/exec.go?name=go1.1.2#739):

```
func indirect(v reflect.Value) (rv reflect.Value, isNil bool) {
    for ; v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr || v.Kind() == reflect.Interface; v = v.Elem() {
        if v.IsNil() {
            return v, true
        }
        if v.Kind() == reflect.Interface && v.NumMethod() > 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    return v, false
}
```

This method is called to get to the deepest value of a reflected value.
Suppose you have a pointer on a pointer on a pointer, this function will get return the
last of these. The same goes for interface values. The crux is that as soon as a 
interface value has more than 0 methods, the indirection stops there. Exactly the
behaviour you're describing.

As this seems to be intended behaviour, what you can do is to define a `Title() string` 
method in your interface and let it return the string.

Comment: Tks for this - in terms of structure for my project it doesn't work to put the Title() method on the interface, but yeah I get the factors involved.  I ended up using an interface{} type field when I need easy access from templates.  It's not perfect, but workable; and it's clear what's happening.